# Reconstruct $@ and keep the correct word split in Bash

Tags: bash, expansion

I have a bash function that passes all the parameters to another function `b` which works well in the past.

```
a () {
  b "$@"
}

a -input /input -output "with blanks"
```

Now I want modify some parameters and passes the updated parameters to `b`.

I was thinking to reconstruct a copy of `$@` to a variable `ARGV`. I have tried to use ', ", and even tab' to keep the fields. But they all failed.

Do you have any good ideas?

What's the data type of $@ and Why it captures the fields correctly?

#### Reference

Using '

```
  ARGV=""

  while [ $# -ne 0 ] ; do
    case "$1" in
      -*)
        ARGV="$ARGV $1 '$2'"
        shift; shift; continue;;
    esac
  done
```

Using "

```
  ARGV="$ARGV $1 \"$2\""
```

Using tab

```
  IFS=$'\t'
  ARGV="$ARGV $1 "$'\t'"$2"$'\t'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can, for instance, put the parameters into array

```
X=("$@")
```

torture it to your liking. and restore back to positional parameters

```
set -- "${X[@]}"
```

or pass it elsewhere

```
./elsewhere "${X[@]}"
./elsewhere "$@"
```